# Searching in Datatable using Paginate-v2 plugin

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to connect MongoDB with nodejs and fetching data from MongoDB server and showing into the HTML page which has Datatable. So the Fetching of data is occurring on the server side.I am successfully getting the data from MongoDB and paginate them with the help of Paginate-v2 plugin. But now the search is not working of datatable. Pagination -v2 has one function name **populate** to do searching in datatable but it's not working for me. Please help me with this. Below is my Node JS code.

NodeJs code

```
    app.get('/gettable',(req,res)=>{
        console.log(req.query);
    user.find({}).populate({
        select:'name',
        match: { 'name': 'Graiden Waller' }
    }).exec((err, user) => {
      console.log(user.name) ;

    }).paginate({},{
            page:Math.ceil(req.query.start / req.query.length) + 1,
            limit:parseInt(req.query.length),
            populate:{
                match:{
                    name:'Graiden Waller'
                }
            }
        },function(err,result){
            console.log(result);
            var mytable = {
                draw:req.query.draw, 
                recordsTotal:0,
                recordsFiltered:0,
                data:[],  

            }
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.json(mytable);
            } else {
                if(result.totalDocs > 0) {
                    mytable.recordsTotal = result.totalDocs;
                    mytable.recordsFiltered = result.totalDocs;

                    for(var key in result.docs) {
                        mytable.data.push([
                            result.docs[key]['name'],
                            result.docs[key]['lastname'],
                            result.docs[key]['email'],
                            result.docs[key]['pass'],
                            result.docs[key]['birthdate'],
                            result.docs[key]['zipcode'],
                            result.docs[key]['phonenumber'],
                        ]);
                    }
                  }
                  res.json(mytable);
 } });
```

Whenever I use populate, it showing me this error `Cannot read property 'count' of undefined` I don't know what should I write for searching in a data table.Please help me for this issue.